# It seems like all major events in the life of Jesus/Yeshua happened on biblical holy days, is this true for the fall festivals as well?

Tags: revelation

Passover, of course, is when Jesus/Yeshua was crucified, announcing the keeping of this day now called “the Supper of the Lamb” or communion. Next is Pentecost or Shavuot where the book of Ruth is often read by the Jewish.  The former Holy Tabernacle was destroyed in 67 AD, as was predicted by Jesus, who said it would be rebuilt in three days, speaking of his own bodily resurrection from the dead. First fruits, of which Jesus would be the first of many who will be saved and have life eternal as they find Him as the ultimate sacrifice for sins as genuine Christ-like believers.  The 50 days of counting the omer, which signifies Pentecost. Christians who were alive when Jesus resurrected and ascended experienced the Holy Spirit come down as tongues of fire on their heads in the first church located in the upper room of the Last Supper in Jerusalem. (It is still there to this day.)

Now, in the Fall festivals, Rosh Hashanah celebrates the new year, but it also begins the Feast of Trumpets, and we read in the book of Revelation; not only the ceremony and detail of the Supper of the Lamb but also about the bowls and the trumpets that are poured out on the Earth in the last days, so then we prepare ourselves with the ten days of Awe for Yom Kippur, which to me signifies the sacrificial ceremony involving two goats. Jesus/Yeshua and Jesus-Barabbas; one being the scapegoat, which was sacrificed.

Actually, they chose to save the fake Messiah and kill the true Messiah, and we go closer to Yom Kippur by repentance, fasting, and prayer; that we may be not only written in the Lamb's Book of Life but in the sealing through recognition and submission to our God-given destiny. “Christ in you, the hope of glory” Colossians 1:27.

We draw closer to the final trumpet during the next festival, Sukkot or the Feast of Booths.  We experience our temporary home without forgetting our ministry. Here we wave four different species of plants again another symbol of the first fruits from heaven and earth, being connected, and in sync with YHVH/G-d in heaven.

Finally, the last Trump is blown during this feast of tabernacles which we read in the Scriptures that “the word became flesh and tabernacles amongst us” (John 1:14). I choose to call this, our final destination moment typically found at the end of September or mid-October.  I feel confident, this could be the time that our Lord Messiah returns once and for all. Is this something we can discuss joyfully, prayerfully, and without bias?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. I recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: What about Jesus' birthday? That is a major event in two of the gospels but does not seem to be associated with any Jewish holiday.

Comment: This is an important matter to consider. Sadly, most are blissfully unaware of the original Holy Days God implemented and many who do know of them, think they have been replaced by the days men have initiated. God never does anything that doesn't point to a future, grander fulfillment. +1

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that some of the events in Jesus' life occurred during a Jewish festival (such provided crowds for teaching), many did not.  Here is a sample:

- Jesus' baptism, Matt 3:13-17, John 1:31-34
- The sermon on the mount, Matt 5-7
- healing the man with leprosy, Matt 8:1-4
- healing the centurion's son, Matt 8:5-13
- Jesus' temptations in the wilderness, Matt 4:1-11, Luke 4:1-13
- Jesus' opening sermon and start of preaching ministry, Luke 4:14-30
- Calling of the first disciples, Luke 5:1-11
- Jesus' first miracle, John 2:1-11
- Jesus teaches Nicodemus, John 3:1-21
- Jesus feeds 5000, John 6:1-15

There are dozens more.

Answer (score 0):

**Festival Fulfillments** It is true that some major events in Christ's ministry happened on or during Holy Festivals. Most notable are Passover = Crucifixion, and Pentecost = Holy Spirit outpouring in response to Jesus request to the Father.

Also the Festival of Lights (Hannakah) was preempted by Jesus, declaring that He was the Light of the World! There was an act of pouring out of Water in a festival that provided an opportunity to declare that He was the true Source of Water.

While it is custom for some commentators to see a fulfillment of the Feast of Tabernacles in some future event prophetically, the verse that was quoted in this Question pointed us to its fulfillment in the Incarnation of Christ!  (John 1:14 *The Word became flesh and tabernacled among us*.) Notice also that the middle  Name given to Jesus by the angel was **Immanuel** which means "God with us."

It is more than safe to say that Jesus is the fulfillment of the Old Testament which was a type  or shadow of the New Testament realities (See the book of Hebrews for more in depth mention of the metaphorical use of the Old Testament.)